# Inicia Splash pero depsues se cierra la app

Tags: java, android

**Splash**

```
    public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Set the duration of the splash screen
    private static final long SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Start the next activity
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(
                        Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);

                // Close the activity so the user won't able to go back this
                // activity pressing Back button
                finish();
            }
        };

        // Simulate a long loading process on application startup.
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeGallo.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />/<!--Quita ActionBar/ToolBar-->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar, Gracias.

Comment: Agrega tu mensaje de error desplegado en LogCat .

Answer (score 1):

Realiza el intent de esta forma, **obteniendo el contexto mediante `getApplicationContext()`** :

```
  TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Start the next activity
            //Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
             Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(mainIntent);

            // Close the activity so the user won't able to go back this
            // activity pressing Back button
            finish();
        }
    };

// Simulate a long loading process on application startup.
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Debes asegurar que MainActivity no tenga algún problema ya que podría ser otra causa que se cierre tu aplicaciòn.

Comment: El problema era el style que yo cree, eso era lo que causaba el problema del cierre de la app, muchas gracias.

Comment: Pueden ser varias situaciones si no agregas el LogCat, en cuanto al intent requieres del contexto.